# How do I resolve this web scraping issue

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape a webpage in R.

```
page <- read_html("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/") 
header_nodes <- html_nodes(page, css = ".titleColumn a" )
rating_nodes <- html_nodes(page, css = "strong")
```

I am trying to extract the movie titles and ratings but I get this error:

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : ICU init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this :

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/'
webpage <- url %>% read_html()

title <- webpage %>% html_nodes('td.titleColumn a') %>% html_text()
title

#[1] "The Shawshank Redemption"                                            
#[2] "The Godfather"                                                       
#[3] "The Godfather: Part II"                                              
#[4] "The Dark Knight"                                                     
#[5] "12 Angry Men"                                                        
#[6] "Schindler's List"                                                    
#[7] "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King"             
#...
```

To get ratings :

```
ratings <- webpage %>% 
            html_nodes('td.ratingColumn strong') %>% 
            html_text() %>% as.numeric()
ratings
#[1] 9.2 9.1 9.0 9.0 8.9 8.9 8.9 .....
```

Comment: Hello @Ronak Shah, how do you know what node to use? I mean, you use `td.titleColumn a` but how do you know that it is the node where to extract that info?

Comment: I usually go to the webpage, right click on the specific text we are looking for and select inspect element which will give that information.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy! `<a href="..." title="Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman">The Shawshank Redemption</a>` so you take the value at the beginning of the tag and the parent `td`. Thanks @Ronak Shah!

Comment: Let me check that @Ronak Shah! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I run your exact codes and still produces the same error. I do not know if it is my r version. I'm using version 3.6.3

Comment: Hello @KwadwoAmoako, I ran the script provided by Ronak and the results were fine (I should note that the results were not in English though). Have you tried to reinstall rvest? `install.packages("rvest")`

Comment: @Manu Thanks a lot. I had to reinstall my R and now everything works.

Comment: You welcome @KwadwoAmoako, please accept the answer from Ronak Shah by clicking in the check (where you see a number with an arrow up and down) below you can check.